# locale.getDisplayName() sometimes works, sometimes does not

Tags: java, android, locale

I am writing an android app that helps people to practice foreign languages. There are two buttons that allow the users to choose between the languages. The text of the buttons then change accordingly. Also, the chosen languages are saved and reload the next time the app starts.

I use the following method to do this:

```
public static Locale[] language = new Locale[2];
public static TextToSpeech[] tts = new TextToSpeech[2];
private Button[] langButton = new Button[2];

public void setLanguageTtsButton(int listNum) {
        tts[listNum].setLanguage(language[listNum]);
        String s = language[listNum].getDisplayName().replace("(", "\n(");
        langButton[listNum].setText(s);
    }
```

And no other codes in the whole app set those button's text.

The problem is sometimes it works correctly and has the buttons display, for example, English(United States), Chinese(Simplified Han, China), etc. However, sometimes it just shows the original locale code, such as en_us, zh_ch_#hans, etc.

Does anyone know why? How can I make sure it displays the correct words more consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you construct the `Locale` object

Here are examples with their outputs

```
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("ENGLISH", "US").getDisplayName());  // english (United States)
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("ENGLISH").getDisplayName()); // english
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("En").getDisplayName()); // English
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("ENGLISH", "CA").getDisplayName()); // english (Canada)
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("ENGLISH", "AU").getDisplayName()); // english (Australia)
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("ENGLISH", "EG").getDisplayName()); // english (Egypt)
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("ENGLISH", "CA", "Canadian").getDisplayName()); // english (Canada,CANADIAN)
Log.d("TAG", new Locale("en_us").getDisplayName()); // en_us
```

Comment: You are right. We need to see how OP constructs their Locale objects.

Comment: Indeed! That was the cause of the problem!
I checked and found that it is related to the part that I used locale.toString() to save the locale, then locale = new Locale(string) to get back.
I changed them to locale.toLanguageTag() and locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(string) respectively. This fixed the problem!
Thanks a lot!